# Настройка шлюза на CentOS

Tags: iptables, centos

Требуется настроить машину как гейт. Закрыть все кроме пары проброшенных наружу портов с другой машины. Изнутри должен быть доступ в интернет через NAT.

В сети работает dhcp, выдаются IP и другие настройки, но машина не работает как gateway.

Возможно я не правильно iptables настраиваю или нужно что-то доставить? Может есть толковый ман по iptables для чайников?

В iptables был дописан:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o внешний_интерфейс -j MASQUERADE
```

В соответствующий файл дописан

```
FORWARD_IPV4=YES
```

DHCPD выдает как гейт внутренний IP машины.

Решение найдено:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADEiptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPTiptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPTecho 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

редактируем /etc/sysctl.conf

меняем *net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0* на *net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1*

спасибо gecube за помощь в настройке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что *конкретно* не работает?

Проверяйте по пунктам:

1. Из внутренней сети Ваш gateway виден?
2. Из внешней сети gateway виден?
3. Пакеты идут из внутренней сети во внешнюю?
4. Наоборот?
5. Какие IP назначены на интерфейсы gateway?
6. DHPCD на внутреннюю сеть нормально работает? Настройки сети (шлюз, маска, пр.) для клиентов нормальные прописываются?

Для меня лично сложностью было настроить вариант dhcp на внутреннем интерфейсе, динамический адрес от провайдера на внешнем + routing + NAT. В результате все удалось сделать на FreeBSD с ipfw + natd. Правда, пришлось сделать хак - allow all to all, но меня это особо не колышет, т.к. NAT автоматом прикрывает доступ из внешней сети ко внутренним машинам.

Comment: я полагаю 3й и 4й пункт

Comment: А если поточнее?

Comment: Поточнее я не понимаю, как это организовать) Я в первый раз такую тему настраиваю.